# Would the Event Horizon Telescope be able to produce a superior image of Betelgeuse?

Tags: event-horizon-telescope, betelgeuse

Current images of Betelgeuse are already amazing, but I was wondering if the EHT could be able to make a significantly better image, given that Betelgeuse is pretty big and pretty bright?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Presumably, yes, EHT observations could improve on existing radio observations of Betelgeuse (e.g. [recent ALMA images](https://alma-telescope.jp/en/news/betelgeuse-201801) and [comparatively ancient VLA images](https://public.nrao.edu/news/vla-shows-boiling-in-atmosphere-of-betelgeuse/)). Any observations would likely be targeted at known [photospheric mm or super-mm](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/30515/2153) emission from the star, mapping radius and temperature changes. The ALMA data showed the existence of a spot $\sim1000$ K hotter than neighboring regions, which would ideally teach us something about convection inside the star.

With a (current) resolution of a couple tens of microarcseconds at $\lambda\sim1.3$ mm, the EHT would indeed improve on existing interferometer results by orders of magnitude (which I *believe*, in the case of ALMA, are the highest-resolution images of Betelgeuse, period, at any wavelength).

Comment: related: [What will it finally take to accurately measure the distance to Betelgeuse?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/36365/7982)